# Resync iCloud photo library and stream

Tags: icloud, photo-stream

I have an iPhone and an iPad where I sync my photos and videos on iCloud with the photo library. Now I have deactivated the photo library on my iPad because I created some videos that exceeded the 5GB limit and did not sync.

Later I deleted these videos and freed some storage on iCloud, but I cannot activate iCloud photo library again on my iPad because it says I do not have enough storage space on iCloud. My photos are 3GB+ and I only have 1GB free space on iCloud. But the photos on my iPad are the exact same ones as on my iCloud, except a few.

Why does it not sync and how can I fix this?

If I now take a photo on my iPad it does not upload to iCloud and sync to my other devices.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you empty the "trash" on your iPad? Albums => recently deleted

Comment: @KevinGrabher yes I did empty the trash. I think my problem is related to this one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/184699/after-disabling-icloud-photo-library-cannot-re-enable-due-to-insufficient-iclou